# Getting HTTP/2 Working on Apache 2.4.29 on Debian 8

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, php5, debian-jessie, http2

I am trying to update my apache2 `(Apache/2.4.29 (Debian 8))` server to support `http2`
but after enabling http2 
 with following code, it does not work because of `mpm_prefork` does not support `http2`

```
<IfModule http2_module>
    ProtocolsHonorOrder On
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>
```

**since `mpm_prefork` apache (2.4.29)  does not work with `http2`, I tried using  `mpm_event`/`mpm_worker`
but it does not work, so I enable `mpm_prefork`**

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event 
sudo a2dismod mpm_worker 
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

Since I am still running `php5`
what should I do to have http2 support on Debian8? 
Will I have to update php5 to php7? 
Is there any workaround to use mpm_worker/mpm_event with php5 with http2 support?

**apache error log**

```
[http2:warn] [pid 11992] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11992] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.1.0g configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 11992] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 7):

It's better to upgrade to php7. Install php7.x-fpm and use the mpm_event (or mpm_worker) module:

```
apt-get install php7.x-fpm # install the php-fpm
a2enmod proxy_fcgi
a2enconf php7.x-fpm
a2dismod php7.x # disables mod_php.
a2dismod mpm_prefork
a2enmod mpm_event # enable event MPM. You could also enable mpm_worker.
```

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04, too. Thanks for sharing.